# Filtering from a dropdown with checkboxes in MVC4 in Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor, filter

My goal is to make a filter with multiple selections for 4 different dropdowns. I am posting 1 example but the are all the same just different Model.

My View:

{             `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                         Select a Driver <b class="caret"></b></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<!--Drivers-->           @foreach (var item in Model.DriversVM){<!--Added to pull drivers-->
<!--Drivers-->                 <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                                            <label>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
                                            </label>
                               </li>}

                     </ul>
                   </li>

                </ul>
             </div>`
}

My Controller:

{

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

var Drivers = db.Drivers.ToList();
vm.DriversVM = new List();

foreach (Driver Driver in Drivers)
            {
                DriverVM NewDriver = new DriverVM();
                NewDriver.DriverID = Driver.DriverId;
                NewDriver.Name = Driver.Name;
                vm.DriversVM.Add(NewDriver);
            }

foreach (Project project in projects)
            {
 NewProject.Driver = db.Drivers.Find(project.Driver.DriverId).Name;
            }

return View(vm);
}

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm a novice at this coding thing and I'm wanting to learn as much as possible but have been stuck for a week now.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone might be able to help you if could post a jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'm new to coding and just setup my jsfiddle account so I'm not sure exactly what to include just yet. But here it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/PUMASTAR/77Rqu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how this needed to be fixed. I'm posting my results in the event that someone has a similar issue and wants the answer.

I consulted with my teammates and I was a dummy for not giving my input a name so that I can identify it in the controller with what I needed. Most of the work was in the controller but the view needed to reflect what I needed to have it show.

View:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="ind_dropdown_pos">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a Driver <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> <!--Drivers-->               @foreach (var item in Model.DriversVM)
                                {                                             <!--pull drivers-->

                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="filterDriver" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverID)" />
                                        <label>
                                            <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>}          <!--Added to pull drivers-->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> filterDriver = null, List<int> filterPerson = null, List<int> filterStage = null, List<int> filterVendor = null)
        {
            //var projects = db.Projects.Include(p => p.Driver).OrderByDescending(p => p.DateUpdated); //Sorts the project by most recently updated
            var Drivers = db.Drivers.ToList();
            var Persons = db.People.ToList();
            var Stages = db.Stages.ToList();
            var Vendors = db.Vendors.ToList();
            ProjectIndexVM vm = new ProjectIndexVM();

            vm.ProjectsVM = new List<ProjectDetailsVM>();
            vm.DriversVM = new List<DriverVM>();
            vm.PersonsVM = new List<ProjectPersonVM>();
            vm.StagesVM = new List<StageVM>();
            vm.VendorsVM = new List<VendorVM>();

            vm.FilteredDrivers = new List<string>();
            vm.FilteredPersons = new List<string>();
            vm.FilteredStages = new List<string>();
            vm.FilteredVendors = new List<string>();

            vm.ImageLocated = new List<string>();

            //var Images = db.ImageTable.ToList();   //add the table name of the table used to store the images

            //var projects = db.Projects.Include(p => p.Driver).OrderByDescending(p => p.DateUpdated); //Sorts the most recently updated project  ((WORKS))

            var projects = from p in db.Projects
                           select p;   // Before trying to sort  ((WORKS))

            //var projects = from p in db.Projects.Include(p => p.Driver).OrderByDescending(p => p.DateUpdated)
            //               select p;  // ((Did not work))

            //var projects = from p in db.Projects
            //               where db.Projects.Include(p => p.Driver).OrderByDescending(p => p.DateUpdated)
            //               select p;

            if (filterDriver != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filterDriver.Count; i++)
                {
                    projects = projects.Where(p => (filterDriver.Contains(p.DriverId) == true));

                }

                foreach (int item in filterDriver) { vm.FilteredDrivers.Add(db.Drivers.Find(item).Name); }
            }

            if (filterPerson != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filterPerson.Count; i++)
                {
                    projects = projects.Where(x => x.Project_Person.Any(p => filterPerson.Contains(p.PersonId)));
                }

                foreach (int item in filterPerson) { vm.FilteredPersons.Add(db.People.Find(item).FName + ' ' + db.People.Find(item).LName); }
            }

            if (filterStage != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filterStage.Count; i++)
                {
                    projects = projects.Where(p => (filterStage.Contains(p.Status.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault().StageId) == true));
                }

                foreach (int item in filterStage) { vm.FilteredStages.Add(db.Stages.Find(item).Name); }
            }

            if (filterVendor != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filterVendor.Count; i++)
                {
                    projects = projects.Where(x => x.ProjectVendors.Any(v => filterVendor.Contains(v.VendorId)));
                }

                foreach (int item in filterVendor) { vm.FilteredVendors.Add(db.Vendors.Find(item).Name); }
            }



            foreach (Driver Driver in Drivers)
            {
                DriverVM NewDriver = new DriverVM();
                NewDriver.DriverID = Driver.DriverId;
                NewDriver.Name = Driver.Name;
                vm.DriversVM.Add(NewDriver);
            }

            foreach (Person Person in Persons)
            {
                ProjectPersonVM NewPerson = new ProjectPersonVM();
                NewPerson.PersonID = Person.PersonId;
                NewPerson.Name = Person.FName + ' ' + Person.LName;
                vm.PersonsVM.Add(NewPerson);
            }

            foreach (Stage Stage in Stages)
            {
                StageVM NewStage = new StageVM();
                NewStage.StageID = Stage.StageId;
                NewStage.Name = Stage.Name;
                vm.StagesVM.Add(NewStage);
            }

            foreach (Vendor Vendor in Vendors)
            {
                VendorVM NewVendor = new VendorVM();
                NewVendor.VendorID = Vendor.VendorId;
                NewVendor.Name = Vendor.Name;
                vm.VendorsVM.Add(NewVendor);
            }

            foreach (Project project in projects)
            {
                ProjectDetailsVM NewProject = new ProjectDetailsVM();
                NewProject.ProjectID = project.ProjectId;
                NewProject.Driver = db.Drivers.Find(project.Driver.DriverId).Name;
                NewProject.Title = project.Title;
                NewProject.Objective = project.Objective;
                NewProject.Vendors = new List<string>();
                NewProject.Updates = new List<ProjectUpdateVM>();
                NewProject.ProjectFields = new List<ProjectFieldVM>();
                //NewProject.ImageTable_item = new List<string>();    //add the item from appropriate table of images

                Status projStatus = project.Status.ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault();
                NewProject.Status = new ProjectStatusVM();

                if (projStatus != null)
                {
                    NewProject.Status.StatusId = projStatus.StatusId;
                    NewProject.Status.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(projStatus.Date).ToShortDateString();
                    NewProject.Status.Description = projStatus.Description;
                    NewProject.Status.Stage = projStatus.Stage.Name;
                }

                NewProject.Stages = new List<StageVM>();


                foreach (Project_Vendor item in project.ProjectVendors)
                {
                    string name = db.Vendors.Find(item.VendorId).Name;
                    NewProject.Vendors.Add(name);
                }

                foreach (Project_Field item in project.Project_Field)
                {
                    ProjectFieldVM projField = new ProjectFieldVM();
                    projField.FieldID = item.FieldId;
                    projField.Field = item.Field.Name;
                    projField.Value = item.FieldItem;
                    NewProject.ProjectFields.Add(projField);
                }

                NewProject.ProjectPeopleFields = new List<ProjectPersonFieldVM>();


                //for each field, store as projectpersonfieldvm, add each person in that group to the list
                foreach (Project_Person item in project.Project_Person)
                {
                    ProjectPersonFieldVM personField = new ProjectPersonFieldVM();
                    personField.FieldID = item.FieldId;
                    personField.Field = item.Field.Name;
                    if (NewProject.ProjectPeopleFields.Any(p => p.FieldID == personField.FieldID) != true)
                    {
                        NewProject.ProjectPeopleFields.Add(personField);
                    }
                }

                foreach (ProjectPersonFieldVM item in NewProject.ProjectPeopleFields)
                {
                    item.FieldPeople = new List<ProjectPersonVM>();
                }

                foreach (Project_Person item in project.Project_Person)
                {
                    ProjectPersonVM person = new ProjectPersonVM();
                    person.Name = item.Person.FName + " " + item.Person.LName;
                    NewProject.ProjectPeopleFields.Find(p => p.FieldID == item.FieldId).FieldPeople.Add(person);
                }

                foreach (Stage item in db.Stages.ToList())
                {
                    StageVM stage = new StageVM();
                    stage.StageID = item.StageId;
                    stage.Name = item.Name;

                    NewProject.Stages.Add(stage);
                }
                vm.ProjectsVM.Add(NewProject);
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
```

The Fix:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filterDriver" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverID)" />
```